# Where can i find this piece that connects to the heating element of a stove

Tags: electrical, stove

[image: burned connecter]

I know i have a burned spade connecter in a samsung stove burner but what is the name of the thing that it connects to and where can i find it

Comment: slip on wire connector

Comment: it is called a spade connector tab ... the heating element wire is welded to it ... people confuse welding soldering ... it is not soldered ... you have to replace the whole burner

Comment: Look up the parts list for your particular model of stove, then order it from any one of the large number of online appliance parts repair places. If you have a local appliance parts store, you could take the part number into them to order a replacement. The undamaged connector appears to screw on - not sure if the damaged one screws on or if it's maybe riveted on.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a crimp terminal.

Make sure to get a metal one without any plastic collar.

Make sure that the new one grips tightly. As if they are loose they overheat.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a spade connector tab.

The heating element wire is welded to it.

Some people confuse welding with soldering.

It is not soldered.

You have to replace the whole burner.